# Common Lisp: concatenate multiple values into vector

Tags: common-lisp

I need a function that concatenates multiple values into (simple) vector, similar to `(concatenate )`. However, unlike concatenate, it should be able to handle arguments that are not vectors or sequences.

I.e. it should work like this:

```
(concat #(1 2) 3) => #(1 2 3)
(concat 1 2 3) => #(1 2 3)
(concat 1 #(2 3 4)) => #(1 2 3 4)
(concat #(1 2) 2 #(3 4 5)) => #(1 2 3 4 5)
```

How can I do this? I think I've forgotten some trivial lisp construct that makes it possible.

As far as I can tell, concatenate can't do it. and I'm not quite sure how to use make it with macro (there's `,@` consturct that inserts list into resulting lisp form, but but I'm not quite sure how to distinguish between non-sequences and sequences in this case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `reduce` approach in the other reply is **quadratic** in time.

Here is a **linear** solution:

```
(defun my-concatenate (type &rest args)
  (apply #'concatenate type
         (mapcar (lambda (a) (if (typep a 'sequence) a (list a)))
                 args)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Since we can compute the length of the sequence, we can allocate the result sequence and then copy the elements into it.

```
(defun concat (type &rest items)
  (let* ((len (loop for e in items
                    if (typep e 'sequence)
                    sum (length e)
                    else sum 1))
         (seq (make-sequence type len)))
    (loop with pos = 0
          for e in items
          if (typep e 'sequence)
          do (progn
               (setf (subseq seq pos) e)
               (incf pos (length e)))
          else
          do (progn
               (setf (elt seq pos) e)
               (incf pos)))
    seq))


CL-USER 17 > (concat 'string "abc" #\1 "def" #\2)
"abc1def2"
```

Above works well for vectors. A version for lists is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

```
defun my-concatenate (type &rest vectors)
  (reduce (lambda (a b)
            (concatenate
             type 
             (if (typep a 'sequence) a (list a))
             (if (typep b 'sequence) b (list b))))
          vectors))
```

You can use [`reduce`](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node143.html) with a little modification of `#'concatenate` on your arguments. If one of the arguments is not a sequence, just transform it into a list (concatenate works even with mixed arguments of simple-vectors and lists).

```
CL-USER> (my-concatenate 'list #(1 2 3) 3 #(3 5))
   (1 2 3 3 3 5)

CL-USER> (my-concatenate 'simple-vector #(1 2 3) 3 #(3 5))
   #(1 2 3 3 3 5)

CL-USER> (my-concatenate 'simple-vector 1 #(2 3) (list 4 5))
   #(1 2 3 4 5)
```

**EDIT:** well, you should probably accept the other answer.

Comment: Note that this is a **quadratic** algorithm to solve a **linear** problem.

Comment: OP wrote "similar to `concatenate`". Since concatenate is a non destructive function, i provided a non destructive solution. If you don't need to preserve the original vectors and you want a linear algorithm, you can just use `append` in the lambda.

Comment: My linear solution is also non-destructive. The problem with your solution is that you are concatenating arguments two by two.